# determine if a function is injective

Tags: functions

given $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ $f(x) = x^3 + x$ determine if the function is injective. We say a function is a injective if $f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$

The solutions consider $f(x+1) - f(x) = 3(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + 5/4 > 0$ then conclude that f is injective. Could someone explain this argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x+1) - f(x) = 3(x + 1/2)^2 + 5/4 > 0$ for all $x$, $f$ is strictly increasing.  That is,
$$
\cdots < f(-1) < f(0) < f(1) < f(2) < \cdots
$$
This implies $f(a) \ne f(b)$ for all $a \ne b$.

Comment: thanks, would it be sufficient to just consider the gradient $3x^2 + 1 > 0$ so it is increasing and use your argument?

Comment: @user144464 Yes, that is faster if you are allowed to use calculus.  And that shows it is injective $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, not just $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: this is off-topic, but to show it's surjective, seeing as we showed it is increasing would it be sufficient to simply state that f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 2 so there is no integer x s.t. $f(x) = 1$?

Comment: @user144464 Yep!